# Make documents hidden from Farm and Site Collection admins - is it possible?

Tags: permissions

Don't You know about the subj? Can I make "super-hidden" library where Farm and Site collection administrators have no access?

My idea is to create an event receiver(for example on 'created' event) which will break permissions, don't know if it works.

**upd.:** Yes, thank You **Gautam** for response and link to article! I tried to create console app that removes all permissions but it doesn't work for admin accounts:

```
    public static void DeleteAllPermissions(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        // break inheritance
        if (!listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
        }
    // remove all existing permissions
    while (listItem.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
    {
        listItem.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("OK deleted!");
```

So Yes, I think it is wrong and impossible.

Best regards,
Gennady

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible. Admins will always have full permission over the entire site collection.

> The reality is that with any system somebody has to be the admin, and
>   being the admin means having both privilege and responsibility, and it
>   also means that the users have to not only trust, but believe in their
>   bones that they can trust the admin, and that the admin has to respect
>   and show they deserve that level of trust.

[Hide documents from site collection administrators](https://serverfault.com/questions/74848/hide-documents-from-site-collection-administrators)

Comment: `with great power come great responsibility` - Oncle Ben
:)